# Parsing a basic scripting language

Tags: c++, grammar

I'm working on writing a scripting language with ANTLR and C++. This is my first actual move from ANTLR grammars into the C++ API, so I'd like to know if this would be a good way to structure the grammar (later I will be adding a tree parser or tree rewriting rules though).

```
grammar dyst;

options
{
  language = C;
  output = AST;
  ASTLabelType=pANTLR3_BASE_TREE;
}

program : statement*;

statement : stopUsingNamespaceStm|usingNamespaceStm|namespaceDefineStm|functionStm|defineStm|assignStm|funcDefineStm|ifStm|whileStm|returnStm|breakStm|eventDefStm|eventCallStm|linkStm|classDefStm|exitStm|importStm|importOnceStm|directive;

namespaceDefineStm : 'namespace' ident '{' statement* '}';

usingNamespaceStm : 'using' 'namespace' ident (',' ident)* ';';

stopUsingNamespaceStm : 'stop' 'using' 'namespace' ident (',' ident)* ';';

directive : '@' directiveId argList? ';';

directiveId : ID (':' ID)*;

importOnceStm : 'import_once' expression ';';

importStm : 'import' expression ';';

exitStm : 'exit' expression? ';';

classDefStm : 'class' ident ('extends' ident (',' ident)*)? '{' (classSection|funcDefineStm|defineStm|eventDefStm)* '}';

classSection : ('public'|'private'|'protected') ':';

linkStm : 'link' ident 'to' ident (',' ident)* ';';

eventCallStm : 'call' ident (',' argList)? ';';

eventDefStm : 'event' ident '(' paramList? ')' ';';

returnStm : 'return' expression ';';

breakStm : 'break' int ';';

ifStm : 'if' '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}';

whileStm : 'while' '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}';

defineStm : 'global'? 'def' ident ('=' expression)? ';';

assignStm : ident '=' expression ';';

funcDefineStm : 'function' ident '(' paramList? ')' ('handles' ident (',' ident)*)? '{' statement* '}';

paramList : param (',' param)?;

param : ident ('=' expression)?;

functionStm : functionCall ';';

functionCall : ident '(' argList? ')';

argList : expression (',' expression)*;

//Expressions!
term : functionCall|value|'(' expression ')';

logic_not : ('!')* term;

bit_not : ('~')* logic_not;

urnary : '-'* bit_not;

mult : urnary (('*'|'/'|'%') urnary)*;

add : mult ('+' mult)*;

relation : add (('<='|'>='|'<'|'>') add)*;

equality : relation (('=='|'!=') relation)*;

bit_and : equality ('&' equality)*;

bit_xor : bit_and ('^' bit_and)*;

bit_or : bit_xor ('|' bit_xor)*;

logic_and : bit_or ('&&' bit_or)*;

logic_or : logic_and ('||' logic_and)*;

expression : logic_or;


value : ident|float|int|string|boolean|newObject|anonFunc|null_val;

anonFunc : 'function' '(' paramList? ')' '{' statement* '}';

newObject : 'new' ident ('(' argList ')')?;

ident : ID (('.'|'::') ID)*;

float : FLOAT;

int : INTEGER;

string : STRING_DOUBLE|STRING_SINGLE;

boolean : BOOL;

null_val : NULL_VAL;



FLOAT : INTEGER '.' INTEGER;
INTEGER : DIGIT+;

BOOL : 'true'|'false';

NULL_VAL : 'null'|'NULL';

STRING_DOUBLE : '"' .* '"';
STRING_SINGLE : '\'' .* '\'';

ID : (LETTER|'_') (LETTER|DIGIT|'_')*;

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z';

NEWLINE : ('\n'|'\r'|'\t'|' ')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '#' .* '\r'? '\n' {$channel = HIDDEN;};
MULTI_COMMENT : '/-' .* '-/' {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

If you are wondering about exactly what it is I'm using this for, you can take a look [here](http://dev.redxdev.com/p/dyst).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The grammar itself is pretty unreadable "as is". A rule like:

   ```
   statement : stopUsingNamespaceStm|usingNamespaceStm|namespaceDefineStm|functionStm|defineStm|assignStm|funcDefineStm|ifStm|whileStm|returnStm|breakStm|eventDefStm|eventCallStm|linkStm|classDefStm|exitStm|importStm|importOnceStm|directive;
   ```

   would be far more readable when declared like this:

   ```
   statement 
     :  stopUsingNamespaceStm
     |  usingNamespaceStm
     |  namespaceDefineStm
     |  functionStm
     |  defineStm
     |  assignStm
     |  funcDefineStm
     |  ifStm
     |  whileStm
     |  returnStm
     |  breakStm
     |  eventDefStm
     |  eventCallStm
     |  linkStm
     |  classDefStm
     |  exitStm
     |  importStm
     |  importOnceStm
     |  directive
     ;
   ```
2. You'll want to explicitly end the entry point of your parser, the rule `program`, with the end-of-file token, otherwise your parser might stop parsing prematurely. With `EOF`, you force the parser to read the entire tokens stream.

   ```
   program 
     :  statement* EOF
     ;
   ```
3. Make explicit tokens for keywords, don't mix them inside your parser rules.

   Instead of:

   ```
   importStm 
     :  'import' expression ';'
     ;
   ```

   it's better to do:

   ```
   importStm 
     :   Import expression ';'
     ;

   Import
     :  'import'
     ;
   ```

   This will make your life easier at a later (tree walking) stage. Without explicit lexer tokens, it is unclear for you when debugging what tokens there actually are in your tree.
4. Your lexer rules:

   ```
   STRING_DOUBLE : '"' .* '"';
   STRING_SINGLE : '\'' .* '\'';
   ```

   can never contain either double- or single quotes. So, it's impossible to have a string literal with a double- and single quote in it.

   Better to do something like this:

   ```
   STRING_DOUBLE 
     :  '"' ('\\' ('\\' | '"') | ~('\\' | '"'))* '"'
     ;
   ```

   which will allow a double quoted string to contain double quotes as well.

That's all I saw at a first glance. I didn't look real close, so there might be more that can be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially with the quote thing. I was having trouble with that.

Comment: @Sam, you're welcome. Note that the string literals now also accepts line breaks. If you don't want that, do something like this: `STRING_DOUBLE : '"' ('\\' ('\\' | '"') | ~('\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n'))* '"' ;`